# How to fetch Facebook profile picture & name w/o app?

Tags: facebook

Does anyone have any idea how to fetch profile picture and first + last name of Facebook member by his profile link/ID without authorising app or anything.

Comment: JS or PHP? because you said _"fetch"_ not what URL to use :)

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve that data from following URL:-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAMEORID?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,picture
```

Replace "USERNAMEORID" to fb username or id of specified user.

Comment: Thank you! Can you also please tell me how to export this data?

Comment: I commented the answer to be more illustrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch these data as following:-

```
<?php   
$content = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/myid?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,picture');

$content = json_decode($content, true);
print_r($content); // <- this print data as associative array, You can fetch it and get data
?>
```

I added a `json_decode` function to your code whereas the data coming form facebook graph is `json` format, So i used that function to convert `json` format to object, Then i used `true` parameter to make this object as associative array. Now you can fetch this array normally as any array.

If you need anything else tell me, I'll be happy to help.